# Is the derivative of the convolution of a smooth function with compact support and a $L^1(R)$ function well defined?

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis

If $f\in C^k_c(\mathbb{R^d})$ and $g\in L^1(\mathbb{R^d})$ then we have $f*g\in C^k(\mathbb{R^d})$ where here we are considering $g$ as a specific function. But if instead, we consider $g$ as just an equivalence class, are the convolution and the derivative still well defined? Because in that case, different equivalence class gives us almost everywhere equivalence but when we are taking derivatives at specific points, we need to know the actual values at those points, so in that case the derivative would not be well defined right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is still well defined. The reason is that even if $g = h$ only almost everywhere, we still have $f \ast g = f \ast h$ everywhere. To see this, let $g, h \in L^1$ be in the same equivalence class i.e. $g =  h$ Lebesgue almost everywhere. Then for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$

$$
(f \ast g)(x) - (f \ast h)(x) = (f \ast (g-h))(x) = \int f(x-y) (g(y) - h(y)) dy
$$

The above integral is now the sum of

$$
\int_{\{x \in \mathbb{R}^d: g(x) = h(x)\}} f(x-y) (g(y) - h(y)) dy = \int_{\{x \in \mathbb{R}^d: g(x) = h(x)\}} f(x-y) 0 dy = 0
$$

and

$$
\int_{\{x \in \mathbb{R}^d: g(x) \neq h(x)\}} f(x-y) (g(y) - h(y)) dy = 0
$$

where second computation is due the assumption $\lambda^d \{x \in \mathbb{R}^d: g(x) \neq h(x)\} = 0$. Thus $(f \ast g)(x) = (f \ast h)(x)$.